# (Kivy Python) Resetting ScreenManager Screen Direction After Instance

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to figure out how to only change the screen direction animation in kivy for one certain button press(cancel button which should wipe right instead of left like a forward-navigating button.) Here is what I am doing currently to make this happen:

```
# Cancel Button
        self.cancel = Button(text="Cancel", height=30, width=90,size_hint=(None, None),pos=(300, 350))
        self.cancel.bind(on_release=self.BackFunction)
        self.ids.float_web.add_widget(self.cancel)

def BackFunction(self, *args):
    self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
    self.manager.current = ('input_sc')
```

I am wondering how to reset the direction to left after this animation happens. If I follow the screen change with

```
self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

then it simply makes the direction left inside of BackFunction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to define the `direction` property each time you change the`current` attribute. However, you can do what you want to do binding a function to [`on_complete`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.TransitionBase) event and unbind  within the function itself:

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


kv_text='''\
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
<MyScreenManager>:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    LastScreen:

<FirstScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'first_sc'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            on_release: root.next_screen()

<LastScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'last_sc'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Previous'
            on_release: root.previous_screen()
'''

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def next_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'last_sc'


class LastScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LastScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def previous_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = 'first_sc'
        self.manager.transition.bind(on_complete=self.restart)

    def restart(self,  *args):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.manager.transition.unbind(on_complete=self.restart)


class MySubApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MySubApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```